# Python import fails for copied directory

Tags: python, import, python-import

I had a directory structure like the following for a Python project:

```
my_project
|_ 
   ... 
   dirA
      |_ 
        __init__.py
        scriptA.py
   dirB
      |_
        __init__.py
        scriptB.py
   ...
```

Inside `__init__.py` of `dirA` (`__init__.py` of `dirB` is empty), I have:

```
import os
import glob
__all__ = [os.path.basename(f)[:-3] for f in glob.glob(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) + "/*.py")]
```

Inside `scriptB.py`, I do:

```
from dirA import *
```

And the subsequent code which utilizes the imports works fine.

Then, I copied and pasted the whole project (with a different project directory name: `my_project_new`) in the same directory as the old one, and I start changing the code of `scriptA.py` in this newly duplicated directory. (*Note*: directory structure of `my_project_new` remains exactly the same as above).

After making the changes, I tried to run `scriptB.py` of `my_project_new`, and I found that **it kept importing `dirA` from the original `my_project` directory**, instead of the `dirA` in the current `my_project_new` directory. Why is this?

Further, I moved the original `my_project` folder to a different location, and tried to run `scriptB.py` of `my_project_new` again. It then failed to identify `dirA` altogether. What is happening now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would comment, but I don't have enough reputation. Hopefully my guess is right.

Are there `__init__.pyc` files? Maybe when it compiles the bytecode it stores the absolute path to the imports. Try removing the .pyc files and importing.

Comment: Good suggestion. One of the reasons I like version control, it's very easy to remove the `.pyc`.

Comment: @Logan, thanks for the suggestion. I've just tried delete all the `__init__.pyc` files from the `my_project_new` directory, but it still fails to find the `dirA` when importing in `scriptB.py`.

Comment: Just for kicks, remove the scriptX.pyc files as well.

Comment: @Logan, actually, there is no `.pyc` for those scripts.

Comment: no `.pyc` file is generated after executing `scriptB.py` which fails to import `dirA`.

Comment: So all of the *.pyc files are gone? I would have thought that there would be more than just `__init__.pyc` files. If it still can't find dirA then it sounds like it's not in the pythonpath. To be honest, I was surprised that scriptB.py found dirA in your previous, working example.

Comment: Is there a particular reason that you can't structure dirA underneath dirB? Your root project files can always refer to it via B